# Location for yaml data files in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I am using yaml files to provide initialisation data for the database and also to provide initialisation data for some of my services models.  Where should I store these files in a ruby on rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [ruby_newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597730/ruby-newbie)'s comment and the general lack of other responses, it seems that there is no well defined rails way for this. Reasonable locations are

```
rails_root/data

rails_root/config/data

rails_root/db/data
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be good use case for loading fixed data into a constant without needing to store in a database.  Since this is technically fixed "data" I would suggest putting it in

```
rails_root/db/yaml/

# and you'll have files like

rails_root/db/yaml/measurments.yml
rails_root/db/yaml/locations.yml

# or if you prefer
rails_root/data/yaml/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put any data required for your application to run in the seeds file(db/seeds.rb). http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: The seeds.rb file would be the correct place to load the data in the  database initialisation yaml file, but where do I place the yaml file?

Comment: You could put it in config/constants.  Is there a reason why you need a .yml file at all?

Comment: The data is a lengthy array of hashes of the same format.  It would be easier for a data entry operator to put the data in yml format rather than repeating the hash keys for each hash.  The question also asks about similar data being needed in a services model.  In this case the data will not go into a database but the services model, so db/seeds does not seem to be the right place.

Comment: What do you mean by it will go in the services model?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Suppose I have a services model app/services/temperature.rb that interpolates temperature from a large amount of temperature data.  I could put the raw temperature data in the temperature.rb file, but it seems to me that it would be better to store it in a file say at app/services/temperature.yml?

Comment: It is really a matter of preference I think.  I have seen data like this stored in the following places:  1)db/data
2)  a new folder called data/ under the project
3)  or if this is configuration information keep it under config/data

Answer (score 0):

If you need create a initial database state you can use seeds files in "db/seeds/". After you can use rake to run and create initial state in your database.

In seeds file you can use Rails model without problems and run a follow command rake to create entries.

```
take db:seed
```

You can check Rails Documentation:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data